# Is it possible to run a teamspeak client on the Pi B+?

Tags: pi-b+

I'm trying to create a music bot, but unfortunately I do not have a server. So I was hoping I could use my raspberry pi B+ to run a client. Is this possible? If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think teamspeak is closed source for intel cpus, so no. If the server is yours, you can try to use mumble (TS clone) as server and client instead.